# get clicked text on any windows application

Tags: c#, winapi

There is a dictionary called Babylon. What they can do is: they have this combination of CTRL-right mouse click. When a user does that on any word in any Windows application (MS Word, Acrobat, any other text editor, even on web pages), the application gets the clicked word and searches it in their dictionary. The word doesn't need to be selected. Just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and right click on any word.

How can I implement this? I suppose there is a Windows API for getting the clicked word in such a fashion. I'm implementing this in c#.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/obtain-text-attributes-using-ui-automation

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, it seems that the app developer of the target app should have included ui-automation in his application